# MySQL: "CREATE DATABASE mydb" command hangs

Tags: mysql, hang

On my MySQL 5.6 server, when logged in as root, the command CREATE DATABASE hangs. No error message - nothing. The MySQL error log doesn't show anything special either.

What could I look into to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Try executing SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST from another session and see what it is doing? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't test your suggestion because now the command succeeds. The database must have released a lock. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why has this question been flagged off-topic?  It is a perfectly valid question.  And has also an answer, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short time afterwards I noticed the database was created, and further commands CREATE DATABASE succeeded.  Most likely, the issue was caused by a database lock that was eventually released later.